# Set same dimensions multipolygon and point data

Tags: coordinate-system, r, sf

I'm trying to plot point data (coördinates) on a multipolygoon map. But I can't get them on top of each other and in the right shape.

Underlying projection data of the Netherlands `multipolygon` data:

```
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 3 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 13565.4 ymin: 306846.2 xmax: 278026.1 ymax: 619232.6
epsg (SRID):    28992
proj4string:    +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.4171,50.3319,465.5524,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.87740,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs
```

[Downloadlink to a `.zip` with 4 Geopackage](https://www.imergis.nl/gpkg/2019_voorlopige_bestuurlijke_grenzen_imergis_gpkg.zip) files from the Netherlands

Underlying `point` projection data of coordinates:

```
Simple feature collection with 1466 features and 4 fields
    geometry type:  POINT
    dimension:      XY
    bbox:           xmin: 3.389737 ymin: 50.77106 xmax: 7.187327 ymax: 53.44402
    epsg (SRID):    28992
    proj4string:    +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.4171,50.3319,465.5524,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.87740,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs
```

some rows of data:

```
points <- structure(list(brouwerijnaam = c("Almelosche", "HertogJan", "HertogJan", 
"Bavaria", "Bavaria", "Brand"), begin_datum_jaar = c(1987, 1981, 
1981, 1719, 1719, 1340), eind_datum_jaar = c(1990, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), plaats = c("Almelo", "Arcen", "Arcen", "Lieshout", "Lieshout", 
"Wijlre"), geometry = structure(list(structure(c(52.35192, 6.660562
), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(51.473427, 6.181219
), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(51.473427, 6.181219
), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(51.518607, 5.597416
), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(51.518607, 5.597416
), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(50.832695, 5.895593
), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 50.832695, ymin = 5.597416, 
xmax = 52.35192, ymax = 6.660562), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
    epsg = NA_integer_, proj4string = NA_character_), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(brouwerijnaam = NA_integer_, 
begin_datum_jaar = NA_integer_, eind_datum_jaar = NA_integer_, 
plaats = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"
), class = "factor"), class = c("sf", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Code I used to shape the x and y coördinates in a sf object with the same crs of multipolygon data.

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

points <- df %>%
  filter(!is.na(lon)) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lat", "lon")) 

points <- st_set_crs(brouwerijen_sf, 28992)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = multipolygon) +
  geom_sf(data = points) +
  coord_sf(datum = NA)
```

[image: multipolygon]
[image: Point data]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without your data to be sure, here's my guess.

You need lon, then lat.

```
points <- df %>%
 filter(!is.na(lon)) %>%
 st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"))
```

This is wrong:

<del>points <- st_set_crs(brouwerijen_sf, 28992)</del>

that *assigned* an Oblique Stereographic Alternative (`+proj=sterea`) 
 projection to your multipolygon layer, and gave it the name "points".

You want to assign your points "longlat", 4326 is the EPSG shortcut.

```
points <- st_set_crs(points, 4326)
```

Now it should work. You can `st_transform(points, st_crs(brouwerijen_sf))` in order to transform the points to the projection in use, but geom_sf will do that for you anyhow.

HTH

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake in my question `brouwerijen_sf` should be `points`.

Comment: setting 28992 on longlat is also wrong, can you update the Q?